# persisting Joda Minutes object with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jodatime

I'm using the jadira jars to persist my joda objects with hibernate.
This works fine for all the complex Joda Objects, but I can't find any class to persist a Joda `Minutes`.
Do I need to manually persist the number of milliseconds my Minutes objects represent ?
There is no jadira class that can do that for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it as `int` representing number of minutes in `Minutes` object. There is no jadira mapping for this kind of object. If you would like to retrieve `Minutes` object directly from database without `int -> Minutes` and `Minutes -> int` conversion, consider creating **custom Hibernate Type** - you just need implement hibernate `UserType` interface - example how to create custom user type can be found for example on [this blog](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/11/09/understanding-and-writing-hibernate-user-types/).

Comment: I implemented a simple Minutes to int converter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I added an org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentMinutes class to Jadira Usertype - see http://jadira.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/jadira/usertype/dateandtime/joda/PersistentMinutes.html